# How to use logrotate with cluster?

Tags: node.js

How to use logrotate with cluster node.js module ? What kind of signal logrotate must send to cluster process for reopening log files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible yet, it's one of the first issues of cluster:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster/issues/5

Answer (score 1):

After trying it out by myself this is definitely the answer on your question: https://npmjs.org/package/log4node

Comment: My problem is restify does not go with log4node. Restify is tied to Bunyan.